# If possible, how to set process network priority in Linux? (similar to nice for CPU)

Tags: linux, networking

Is in possible to set network priority for processes similar to how niceness works for CPU?

The use case is to control network bandwidth distribution over processes that download stuff over network (e.g apt, etc).

Comment: Look into "traffic shaping" (there is a command `tc` in linux for this). For PID specific traffic shaping look e.g. into this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328308/how-can-i-limit-download-bandwidth-of-an-existing-process-iptables-tc

Comment: Welcome to SU. Check out [Trickle](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/trickle).